# Send data to a decent user with Kemal over websocket

Tags: websocket, kemal

How can i send data data to a decent user connected via websockets? I know, 
Websocket connections yields the context, but how can i filter a decent socket connection for sending data to only 1 (or some) connected user(s) depending on context (env)?

```
SOCKETS = [] of HTTP::WebSocket
ws "/chat" do |socket,env|
  room = env.params.query["room"]
  SOCKETS << socket
  socket.on_message do |message|
    SOCKETS.each { |socket| socket.send message}
  end
  socket.on_close do
    SOCKETS.delete socket
  end
end
```

Must socket contain the room or needs SOCKETS to be a Hash?

Comment: Show your effort of solving your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store sockets as hash and give id to your clients and then you can send saved socket of your recent client.

I mean that

```
SOCKETS = {} of String => HTTP::WebSocket

socket.on_message do |message|
  j = JSON.parse(message)
  case j["type"]
  when "login"
    user_id = j["id"].to_s
    SOCKETS[user_id] = socket
  when "whisper"
    to = j["to"].to_s
    from = j["from"]
    user = SOCKETS[to].send("#{from} is whispering you!")
end
```

something like that.